# Bluetooth - Blueman applet doesn't work on Debian 10 Cinnamon

Tags: debian, bluetooth, blueman

There is already a great research here and in almost all the internet and I cannot configure bluetooth in Debian 10

When clicking on "devices" an inactive window appears:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iAAk.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfPYK.png)

When trying to set up a new device, receive this message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3otj.png

I'm from Brazil :)

I've been trying to solve the problem for several days and nothing

`$ sudo service bluetooth status`

Output:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor     preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-01-18 22:52:51 -03; 19min ago
Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 9398 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
Memory: 1.1M
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
          └─9398 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

jan 18 22:52:51 desktop-linux systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
jan 18 22:52:51 desktop-linux bluetoothd[9398]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
jan 18 22:52:51 desktop-linux systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
jan 18 22:52:51 desktop-linux bluetoothd[9398]: Starting SDP server
jan 18 22:52:51 desktop-linux bluetoothd[9398]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

Did not find the item "**bluetooth settings**" anywhere here in Debian 10 Cinnamon

How to configure bluetooth on Debian 10 after all?

From what I saw the same problem occurs in Ubuntu

```
sudo rfkill list
```

output:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
```

and:

```
 lsmod | grep bluetooth
```

output:

```
bluetooth             647168  12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,ath3k,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 28672  5 bluetooth,cfg80211
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
```

and:

```
sudo journalctl -b | grep Bluetooth
```

output:

```
jan 19 21:25:04 linux-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
jan 19 21:25:04 linux-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: HCI device and connection    manager initialized
jan 19 21:25:04 linux-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
jan 19 21:25:04 linux-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
jan 19 21:25:04 linux-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
jan 19 21:25:04 linux-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010100.dfu
jan 19 21:25:04 linux-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
jan 19 21:25:15 linux-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
jan 19 21:25:15 linux-desktop bluetoothd[1449]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
jan 19 21:25:15 linux-desktop systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
jan 19 21:25:15 linux-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
jan 19 21:25:15 linux-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
jan 19 21:25:15 linux-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
jan 19 21:25:15 linux-desktop bluetoothd[1449]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
jan 19 21:25:16 linux-desktop systemd[1127]: Starting Bluetooth OBEX service...
jan 19 21:25:16 linux-desktop systemd[1127]: Started Bluetooth OBEX service.
```

Grateful for any help!

I'm sorry. I don't speak english yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the solution here: [bbs.archlinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1607972#p1607972)

```
wget http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2014/01/20623393_919a4673931aa789f0b1c3eeafb360b36097894a.cab
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get install cabextract
```

and:

```
sudo cabextract 20623393_919a4673931aa789f0b1c3eeafb360b36097894a.cab -F *.dfu -d /lib/firmware/ar3k
```

**The error was here of the command `sudo journalctl -b | grep Bluetooth`**:

```
jan 19 21:25:04 linux-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010100.dfu
```

Now:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO6Dl.png]

And:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZR3O.png]